# python script using fabric to remote execute is hanging at connection?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, fabric, ssh-keys

I have a short python script (eventually to be larger) that is remote executing a 'pwd' command on the remote host. I am just testing to connect to the host using SSH keys (yes these are set up correctly). What i have so far seems to work, but it sort of just hangs there in the IDLE window...does not error out, but also if i check the host last login date, it doesn't match when i executed the script. Is there a way to have the output show (similar to expect, so i can see if i am actually even logging in).

Tried to use password instead, same exact behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from fabric import Connection


sshConnection = Connection(
    host = 'hostname.com',
    user='myuser',
    connect_kwargs={
            "key_filename":r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\id_rsa',
            },
)


sshConnection.run('pwd')
close()
```

basically getting this in the IDLE window

> > >
> >     RESTART: /PATH/TO/SCRIPT/ON/WINDOWS/LAPTOP/script.py
> >     |

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use `fabric2.4.0` and `Python 3`

```
from fabric import Connection as connection, task

@task
def deploy(ctx):
    with connection(host=host, user=user) as c:
         c.run('pwd')
```

Put the code above in a file called fabfile.py and you run it from your command line 
`fab deploy`

Comment: problem is, i am executing from windows machine and plan to loop through hundreds of servers. can you execute a fabfile via cygwin command line?

Comment: yes, you can also use git-bash on windows. You can even use Windows command prompt. But ensure you have python 3 installed on your windows machine

Comment: interestingly enough, the script now works at about 30 seconds before a keyboard interruption is necessary otherwise it will hang. 30 seconds gets the output of the pwd command, but does not exit the ssh session after concluding the command. Something that needs to be done to exit the ssh session and log this result appropriately, as opposed to IDLE (stdout or stderr? would that help).